# ngMock fails to recognize request

Tags: http, angularjs, coffeescript, jasmine

I've got the following specs wrapped around a controller. I've got the following Jasmine Spec:

```
 describe 'MyApp.Controller.SomeController', ->
   beforeEach module('mymodule')
   beforeEach inject ($rootScope , $httpBackend, $controller, SomeService) ->
      @scope = $rootScope.$new()
      @httpBackend = $httpBackend
      someService = SomeService
      @someResource = someService.someResource
      $controller 'MyApp.Controller.SomeController', $scope: @scope

   describe "#fetchMethod", ->
     describe "given an object", ->
       beforeEach ->
         @id = 17
         @scope.fetchMethod(@id)
       it "sets due to true", ->
         @httpBackend.whenGET().respond(200, {"someStrings": ["foo", "bar"], otherStrings: ["bar", "goo"]})
         expect(@scope.someStrings).toBeDefined()
         expect(@scope.otherStrings).toBeDefined()
```

Wrapped around the following Controller:

```
 MyApp.Controller.SomeController = (scope, someService) ->

   scope.fetchMethod = (ID)->
      someService.someResource.fetch
      Id: artID
      ,(response) ->
        scope.someStrings = response['someStrings']
        scope.otherStrings = response['otherStrings']
        scope.someStringsExist = true if scope.someStrings
 MyApp.Controller.SomeController.$inject = ['$scope', 'SomeService']
```

Where SomeService is defined as follows:

```
 MyApp.Service.SomeService = (resource) ->
   @someResource = resource '/api/foos/:ID', {},
   fetch:
     method: 'GET'

   @

 MyApp.myModule.service 'SomeService', ['$resource', MyApp.Service.SomeService]
```

This setup appears to function on the site, correctly executing the request and returning values from the (rails) api endpoint.

However, when the jasmine specs are run it fails with:

`Error: Unexpected request: GET /api/foos/17 No more request expected in http://localhost:3000/assets/helpers/angular-mocks.js?body=1 (line 889)`

What am I missing? Why is httpBackend failing to recognize the GET request?

scope.initialize = (artifactId, artifactType)->
    scope.artifactId = artifactId
    scope.artifactType = artifactType
    scope.currentVersionExists = false
    scope.attachmentFetcher(scope.artifactId)

MyApp.Controller.SomeController.$inject = ['$scope', 'SomeService']

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line where you stub the response should go before you make the request:

```
@httpBackend.whenGET().respond(200, {"someStrings": ["foo", "bar"], otherStrings: ["bar", "goo"]})
```